# How do a double complex on second quadrant viewed as a single complex?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors, derived-categories

> Background
>
> Dimca's book "Sheaves in topology" Theorem 2.3.29 (Projection Formula). Let $f : X \rightarrow Y $ be a continuous
> map, $ \mathcal{F^{\cdot}} \in D^{-}(X),  \mathcal{G^{\cdot}} \in D^{-}(Y)$. Then there is a natural isomorphism in $D^{-}(Y),$
> $Rf_!\mathcal{F^{\cdot}} \otimes^L \mathcal{G^{\cdot}} \cong Rf_! (\mathcal{F^{\cdot}} \otimes^L \mathcal{G^{\cdot}})$.

In order to define $Rf_!\mathcal{F^{\cdot}}$, we need to replace $\mathcal{F^{\cdot}}$ by an injective resolution. To construct such resolution, we need to use a double complex, which may occupy the whole second quadrant $x<0, y>0$, assuming cohomology is used. How do we view it as a single complex?

I guess for the i-th piece, we take direct sum/product of all entries on the antidiagonal $x+y=i$. However it involves infinitely many terms, so direct sum and direct product are different. So which one is correct?

Comment: Yes there are missing assumption here. The author quote Iversen for the proof. In the book of Iversen, it is assumed that $X$ has cohomological dimension $n$ so that any bounded above complex $\mathcal{F}^.$ has a bounded above resolution by soft sheaves which may be used to compute the derived functor $Rf_!$. Note also that Iversen assume that the coefficient ring is noetherian.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sense to me. I guess the projection formula doesn't hold for a strange space $X$.

Comment: Probably stated like this, I don't know any counter-example though. But often there are an alternate definition of $Rf_!$ which makes the projection formula true.